# Why is my while loop acting this way?

Tags: c

I am currently trying to get a while loop working, but it's not going the way I want it too. What I want to do is loop until a specific input is put in. Something must be wrong with my syntax, but I can't figure out what.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float input = 0;
    scanf("%f", &input);
    while(input!=0)
    {
        printf("hello\n");
        scanf("%f", &input);

    }
     return 0;
}
```

For some reason, it doesn't break out of the while loop when it is zero. I want the while loop to stop working after someone enters 0, but when someone enters 0 it will create an infinite printing of "hello" instead..As you may have guessed, input becomes 0 whenever the user inputs anything besides a float, so if I enter a letter, I am expecting the while loop to stop, but it doesn't ;\

Edit:

Thank you guys for help! I learned and figured out why my logic was wrong (due to lack of understanding how to test the value of scanf)!! Cheers.

Comment: Welcome to the world of floating point and its never ending issues :)

Comment: You should check the result of `scanf`.

Comment: Thank you, but how should I rework the syntax so that it breaks out of the while loop?

Comment: You might want to read [this `scanf` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), especially the section about what it returns,

Comment: @R.T.: Testing floats against zero exactly should actually work, if the float is zero. If you do any computations you may not be able to guarantee an exact zero, but if you are just inputting numbers then you can make this guarantee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`input` does *not* become zero if the user enters a non-float. `scanf` won't change the value, and it won't consume any characters. So, if the user enters a non-float, `scanf` will keep reading the same characters over and over again.

You can test the `scanf` return value to see if it successfully read anything. `scanf` returns the number of fields that were successfully read, so a return value of 0 means that it failed to parse anything:

```
while(scanf("%f", &input) == 1) {
    printf("You entered %f\n", input);
}
```

Comment: Right, I am sorry, I meant to say what you meant by parsing because I remember if it failed to read it, it would return 0 and 1 if successful.

Answer (score 0):

Write the loop like

```
    while(input!=0)
    {
        printf("hello\n");
        input = 0.0;
        scanf("%f", &input);

    }
```